# Construct all the harmonic frames with three vectors for $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Construct all the harmonic frames with three vectors for $\mathbb{C}^2$.

I have been search for a procedure to do this but I haven't found on.

$\textbf{Definition of Harmonic Frame:}$ The Parseval frame $\{\nu_0,\dots,\nu_{m-1}\}$ defined as $n \leq m$ and $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_m$ and $\nu_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\begin{bmatrix}\omega_1^k \\ \omega_2^k \\ \cdot \\
\cdot \\ \cdot \\ \omega_n^k\end{bmatrix}$ is called a harmonic frame.

Comment: The definition of harmonic frame is now provided in the problem.

Comment: What is $\omega_n$? (e.g. a root of unity?)

Comment: Yes omega is a root of unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is as follows. Let $m$ be the number of frame vectors ($3$ for you) and $n$ the dimension ($2$ for you).

1. Find all $m$ solutions of $z^m=1$ (roots of unity), denoted $\omega_0,\dots,\omega_{m-1}$ in your post.
2. Choose $n$ of them. There are $\binom{m}{n}$ harmonic frames.
3. Write down each frame according to the given formula.

For example, if I choose $1$ and $e^{2\pi i/3}$, the frame vectors are
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\quad 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ e^{2\pi i/3} \end{bmatrix},\quad 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ e^{4\pi i/3} \end{bmatrix}$$
There are two more such frames.